# get all service contract method names

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Am consuming the WCF service from WPF and I want to list all the method names from service.

I have tried with two solutions,
1.

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(TypeOfTheService).GetMethods();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    string methodName = method.Name;
}
```

It lists all functions but it include some other functions also like "to string","open","abort" etc.

---

2.

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(ITimeService).GetMethods();

            foreach (var method in methods)
            {
                if (((System.Attribute)(method.GetCustomAttributes(true)[0])).TypeId.ToString() == "System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute")
                {                 
                    string methodName = method.Name;
                }
            }
```

it ends up in an error showing "Index out of bound".

Comment: Are you sure that every method has an attribute?

Comment: I'd query WCF framework metadata for that. It must know what exact methods exist.

Comment: no,all methods dont have that attribute...thats y its shows array,i want to overcome that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for methods within service contract, i.e. **interface**, it will not contain any methods like `ToString()`:

```
var contractMethods = typeof(ITimeService).GetMethods(); // not TimeService
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the second approach is that not all methods seem to have the `OperationContract` attribute. Thus for these methods, `GetCustomAttributes` returns an empty array. Now, when you try to access the first element of the array, you get this exception.

You can simply do something like this:

```
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (OperationContractAttribute));

if(attribute != null)
{
    //...
}
```

to see if the method has the `OperationContract` attribute.

If what you got is the type of the service itself, you could get all of the interfaces it implements, get all of their methods, and then check if such methods have the `OperationContract` attribute like this:

```
var methods =
    typeof (TimeService).GetInterfaces()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetMethods())
    .ToList();

foreach (var method in methods)
{
    var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(OperationContractAttribute));

    if (attribute != null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: this function "method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (OperationContractAttribute));" returns null always.

Comment: Are you testing on `ITimeService`?  or `TypeOfTheService`?

Comment: using TypeOfTheService.

Comment: In your question, in the second approach, you are using `ITimeService`. Try that and it would work. Or do you need to start from `TypeOfTheService`?

Comment: oh sorry,its mistaken,i had copied my little earlier code,Please look this
MethodInfo[] methods = cs.GetType().GetMethods();
            string [] methodName=new string[methods.Length];
            names.ItemsSource = stringlist;            
            foreach (var method in methods)
            {
               stringlist.Add(method.Name);
            }

Comment: @rav, I am not sure I understand. Do you have a reference to the contract type? i.e., the type of the interface. Or do you only have a reference to the type of the service? i.e., the class.

Comment: i have reference to the type of service.

Comment: That solution worked almost,but i have another issue on the same.
[0]: "GetData"
[1]: "GetDataAsync"
[2]: "GetDataUsingDataContract"
[3]: "GetDataUsingDataContractAsync"
    

The above is the value returned in that loop.
The only function am using is the first one "GetData",others are unwanted functions comes automatically.

Comment: Why are these unwanted?

Comment: Those functions are not created by me,it automatically comes while calling.Dont know from where it comes.